# C++ std thread and list Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++, multithreading, list, thread-safety, std

I am new to multi-threading and I am going to pass a list in thread.

I hope a thread can add a string and the other will remove a string.

I am confused how to pass the list.

here is part of my code and it got Segmentation fault (core dumped)

```
struct BOOK {
    list<string> bookName;
};

class itemE {
    ...

    itemE():
        bookList((BOOK*)malloc(sizeof(BOOK)))
    {
        count = 0;
        m_addThread = thread(&itemE::add, this, ref(bookList->bookName));           
        ...
    }   

    void add(list<string>& bkName)
    {
        ...
            m_mutex.lock();
            bkName.push_back(name);
            m_mutex.unlock();
        ...
    }

};
```

I tried modified that

```
m_addThread = thread(&itemE::add, this, bookList);
```

with

```
void add(BOOK* bk)
{
    ...
        bk->bookName.push_back(name);
    ...
}
```

but it still the same

Comment: 1. if you got a core file, _look at it_. They're not just there to waste your disk space, it's supposed to help you debug. 2. The first argument to the `std::thread` constructor is a callable. Is your member function a regular callable? What does the syntax look like when you call it from outside your class?

Comment: problem is not with `thread` but `malloc` function and `bookList->bookName`, `bookName` after calling malloc is not created, use new to allocate memory and construct object.

Comment: If you're using malloc in C++, and not doing something advanced like writing your own allocator, then you are almost certainly doing something wrong.

Comment: thank you @Useless to remind me the debug method, I will  try it and share the result later

Comment: thand you @Useless it really help me a lot!! after I new BOOK() I forgot to join my thread. But by reading the core file and google I found it and it  work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itemE::add` is body of your thread, in this function member you call `push_back` on `bkName` list, but this object was not constructed - and you got segmentation fault.

`malloc` function only allocates memory. Calling this line `malloc(sizeof(BOOK))` only `sizeof(BOOK)` bytes were allocated, but constructor of `bookName` member was not called. You should use `new` to allocate memory and construct your BOOK object.

```
itemE():
    bookList(new BOOK)
{
  ...
```

in `new BOOK` default constructor of `list<string> bookName` will be called, and then you can use for exmaple `push_back` on this member.

Comment: Ugh, I didn't notice that. @OP - learn to write single-threaded code correctly before trying to create multiple threads. This is utterly basic stuff you ought to understand before trying anything complex.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using lambda instead

```
itemE()
 :bookList(new BOOK)
{
    count = 0;
    m_addThread = thread([this]() { add(bookList->bookName); });  

}
```